# Custom core API calls with dropbox.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dropbox-api

I'm trying to make a custom Core API call that dropbox.js doesn't wrap around -- specifically to get a link to [streamable media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media).

How can I use dropbox.js's provided [Dropbox.Util.Xhr](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Util/Xhr.html) to make this request? I'm not sure on how to include the access token or set up the request at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do that, but based on [the docs](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html), I think this will work to make a `/media` call (completely untested code):

```
var path = '/path/to/file';
client.makeUrl(path, { download: true }, function (error, link) {
    alert('Got back URL: ' + link.url);
}
```